# What is the best practice to render an image in MVC from one call to get an aggregate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, viewmodel

I have an issue that I would like some opinions on. I totally understand that I CANNOT render an image (byte[]) directly from my viewmodel. I understand that I need to have an id that represents my image in my view model.

Once I bind my viewmodel to my view I can then do something like the following:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetPhoto", new { photoId = Model.PhotoId })" />
```

And then this:

```
public ActionResult GetPhoto(int photoId)
{
    byte[] photo = GetPhotoFromDb(photoId);
    return File(photo, "image/jpeg"); 
}
```

However, I have a call to a 3rd party web service (I do not control this) that I call to get an aggregate that populated my viewmodel. Some thing like this:

```
-Vehicle
  -VehicleId
  -VehicleName
  -VehicleImage byte[] <=======
  -VehicleServiceHistory
    -ServiceHistoryId
    -SericeType
    -ServiceTitle
```

So in theory I could call up the 3rd party web service people and say, I know you are already giving my the VehicleImage in the aggregate (above) but can I please have a separate call to a new service method called GetImageById(int imageId).

So lets assume they say **no**. So all I have is an aggregate of data that already has my image but I know I have to load the image to the view separately like I stated above:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetPhoto", new { photoId = Model.PhotoId })" />
```

I could do something nasty like add the image to session when the aggregate comes down from the web service and interrogate session to get the image back with the photoId  **but there is no way I want to do this.**

Can anyone give me any ideas on how I can utilize the, already available, image in the aggregate without having to do another call.

Note: I am totally ok with calling a separate action:

```
public ActionResult GetPhoto(int photoId)
{
    byte[] photo = GetPhotoFromDb(photoId);
    return File(photo, "image/jpeg"); 
}
```

But I want to use the image that was already supplied in the aggregate in this action and not have to call the service again.

Looking forward to hearing your suggestions.

thanks
RuSs

Note: This post has been up here for a couple of weeks, surely someone has an opinion!! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is that you have to populate the view model that would contain an id of the image you want to render.

Once the viewmodel has rendered you must call another controller action like this:

```
public ActionResult GetPhoto(int photoId()
{
    byte[] photo = GetPhotoFromDb(photoId);
    return File(photo, "image/jpeg"); 
}
```

After much investigation it seem this is just the way it is unless all browsers support data URI scheme.

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@Html.Raw(Convert.ToBase64String(Model.VehicleImage))" />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

> I totally understand that I CANNOT render an image (byte[]) directly from my viewmodel

Well actually you can if the browser supports the [`data URI scheme`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@Html.Raw(Convert.ToBase64String(Model.VehicleImage))" />
```

Other than that there are not much choices left. You will have to persist the image somewhere on the server between the 2 HTTP calls. I congratulate you for the fact that you do not wish to use the Session for that. It's not the right storage for that. One possibility would be to persist the image on some folder on your server (shared folder if you are running on a webfarm) and then only reference the image by id. So basically you will be caching the remote images on your infrastructure. You could have some scheduled scripts that are deleting files older than some date that you could define.

Comment: hi darin, what is the use of using `Convert.FromBase64String`, does it optimize image to load faster in sites ?